# date now javascript convert format

Tags: javascript

how to convert timeInMs to this format dd/mm/yyyy

```
var timeInMs = Date.now();
alert(timeInMs);

//convert to dd/mm/yyy
```

is there any advantage of using jquery when dealing with time/date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var date = new Date();

var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
var month = date.getUTCMonth();
var day = date.getUTCDate();

//month 2 digits
month = ("0" + (month + 1)).slice(-2);

//year 2 digits
year = year.toString().substr(2,2);

var formattedDate = day + '/' + month + "/" + year;
```

prints 25/10/13

Comment: nice answer, but how to use date.now()? it's faster than date.get

Comment: new Date() instance is set to the current timestamp (now).